# Selenium Webdriver Unable to create chrome webdriver instance

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

We've been running integration tests successfully against Ruby on Rails 2 using Selenium on both Google Chrome and Firefox.  However, we've recently upgraded to Ruby on Rails 3 and are running into issues creating a Google Chrome webdriver instance.

When we attempt to create, we get the following stack:

```
irb(main):002:0> profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
translate])#<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile:0x64f2fd0 @extensions=[], @model=nil>
irb(main):003:0> profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
false
irb(main):004:0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :profile  => profile,     :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate])
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
  from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:157:in `open'
  from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:157:in `ip'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:170:in `interfaces'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:23:in `free?'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:5:in `above'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
    from /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from (irb):4
```

Any tips?

Comment: Same issue also occurs when trying to instantiate the firefox webdriver.

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Chrome? What version of the Chrome Driver?

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra, driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :profile  => profile,     :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate])

Comment: The code is shown in the irb session pasted into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this when I had included a [gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) which included the *[backports](https://rubygems.org/gems/backports/versions/3.24.1)* gem as part of its dependencies into my Gemfile. The *backports* gem rewrites some Ruby 1.8 internals, which overwrote parts of the `UDPSocket` core class. Try getting rid of the *backports* gem and giving it a shot.

Comment: Another solution consists in reporting the problem :-)
This is fixed in the latest release of `backports`. See https://github.com/marcandre/backports/issues/67

Answer (score 1):

**ChromeDriver Installation:**

Download Chromedriver 2.x from "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.8/."

Unzip it and save it in a folder on any drive. Set *path* by the following steps:

- Copy the path till chromedriver.exe
- Right click on *Computer* and select ‘Properties’
- Select ‘Advanced system variables’
- Select ‘Environment variables’
- Click on <kbd>Edit</kbd> button for ‘Path’ variable of ‘User variables’
- Append the chromedriver path
- Save changes.

**Run Selenium Test:**

Now run your Selenium test. It will run in the Chrome browser.

**Sample Code**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
$driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.co.in/"
$driver.manage().window().maximize()
$driver.quit()
```

**Note**: You need to install the latest chromedriver for the latest version of the Chrome browser

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Comment: For [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7)?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an interference with the `backports` gem and the fact that the `socket` library reuses `IO.open` although it changes the interface.

Upgrading `backports` to [v2.6.7 or above](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/issues/67) should resolve this.